# Jquery image show/hide not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a supposedly-simple jquery task in my app that changes an image based on which thumbnail is clicked.  The HTML/erb is like this:

```
    <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/Airblades.png" id="#main1" class="main-image">
    <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/HU02+V+(Sprayed+Nickel).jpg" id="#main2" class="main-image hidden">
    <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/AB14+White+LV+(301854-01).jpg" id="#main3" class="main-image hidden">
    <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/WD05+Long+(247663-01).jpg" id="#main4" class="main-image hidden">
    <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/9kJ+Steel+Front.jpg" id="#main5" class="main-image hidden">

    <div class="row thumb-container">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/Airblades.png" id="#thumb1" class="thumbnail active">
      </div> <!-- col -->
      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/HU02+V+(Sprayed+Nickel).jpg" id="#thumb2" class="thumbnail">
      </div> <!-- col -->
      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/AB14+White+LV+(301854-01).jpg" id="#thumb3" class="thumbnail">
      </div> <!-- col -->
      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/WD05+Long+(247663-01).jpg" id="#thumb4" class="thumbnail">
      </div> <!-- col -->
      <div class="col">
        <img src="https://lagunagreenworks.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/Images/9kJ+Steel+Front.jpg" id="#thumb5" class="thumbnail">
      </div> <!-- col -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
```

And the jquery is like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thumb1").click(function(){
      $(".main-image").addClass("hidden");
      $(".thumbnail").removeClass("active");
      $("#thumb1").addClass("active");
      $('#main1').removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $("#thumb2").click(function(){
      $(".main-image").addClass("hidden");
      $(".thumbnail").removeClass("active");
      $("#thumb2").addClass("active");
      $('#main2').removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $("#thumb3").click(function(){
      $(".main-image").addClass("hidden");
      $(".thumbnail").removeClass("active");
      $("#thumb3").addClass("active");
      $('#main3').removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $("#thumb4").click(function(){
      $(".main-image").addClass("hidden");
      $(".thumbnail").removeClass("active");
      $("#thumb4").addClass("active");
      $('#main4').removeClass("hidden");
    });
    $("#thumb5").click(function(){
      $(".main-image").addClass("hidden");
      $(".thumbnail").removeClass("active");
      $("#thumb5").addClass("active");
      $('#main5').removeClass("hidden");
    });
  });
</script>
```

The CSS doesn't really affect the problem as it's working fine on the initial page load, but here it is:

```
.product-page .main-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
}

.product-page .thumb-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.product-page .thumbnail {
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.product-page .thumbnail.active {
  border: thin $color-light-grey solid;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqd3suwa/2/) of my issue.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, remove the `#` in `id="#thumb1"`... And in every element that you have in your HTML.

Comment: hello, when you say *changes an image*, what do you mean exactly? are all images supposed to be hidden by default until its thumbnail is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first problem that I see is way You are reffering to an DOM element You are using:

```
$("#thumb2").click(function()...
```

*$('#id')* notation is looking for element with **id="id"** You are looking for element with **id="thumb2"** but in Your code there is an element with **id="#thumb2"**

do You see it now ? I didn't test rest of the code but this is certainly one of the issues here.

Comment: Argh!  How long have I been staring at this and it's something moronic.  Thank you.  Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with how you have defined the ids in your `html`.

For example you have the id set as `#thumb3`

```
<img src="url.jpg" id="#thumb3" class="thumbnail">
```

Change this to just `thumb3`

```
<img src="url.jpg" id="thumb3" class="thumbnail">
```

With `CSS` and `jQuery` you access ids with the `#` selector. After you update this it should work. Check the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vqd3suwa/2/).

Comment: not sure why this is getting downvoted. This is why it isn't working. Check other comment by different user below question and check the working jsfiddle here  - https://jsfiddle.net/vqd3suwa/2/